# Change variable type during runtime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, declare

Is it possible to change a variable type in SQL Server? Something like when you have

```
DECLARE @a INT;
SET @a = 3
```

but later you want to use `@a` to store `VARCHAR`? Is there a way to undeclare it, change the data type it can store? Does T-SQL allow this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @s sql_variant
select @s=3
select @s='hello'
```

Answer (score 4):

Variables names must be unique in a sql batch once declared you cannot change the type .

```
 Declare @a int
 Set @a=4
 Select @a

Declare @a varchar(10)
set @a='Sample'
Select @a
```

You will receive an error

```
 The variable name '@a' has already been declared. Variable names must be
 unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
```

However you can use [go](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) to  end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements and then again declare the variable

```
 Declare @a int
 Set @a=4
 Select @a
 Go
 Declare @a varchar(10)
 set @a='Sample'
 Select @a
```

Else you can use [sql_variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259247%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to  store data of an unspecified.However it cannot be used for  text, ntext and timestamp without conversion